# Eclipse Google SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

So essentially what I have is a libGdx Program that I have written in Eclipse and I want to add in Google Leaderboards to my app. I have looked at what google has posted on their website on how to add BaseGameUtils to your project. I cannot seem to follow and understand how to add BaseGameUtils to my project. I need it most specifically for `GameHelper`. I would appreciate any guidance, step by step instructions, or even screenshot instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alright first of all you need to download the google play services sdk from the sdk manager and install it.

2) you need to download the [Library Project named BaseGameUtils](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/)

3) you need to open eclipse and import the project into the workspace

4)Right-click your project and select Properties

5)Select Android in the list, In the Library panel click add project as library and select the BaseGameUtils and your done...i hope this helps.

Comment: I've found what it is, but when I import BaseGameUtils it has errors that are really confusing me. It is having troubles importing `import com.google.android...`